# C# SQL pass variable to query

Tags: c#, sql

I am currently writing a *Search* function that bring down a value *Name*

Here is my query:

```
"SELECT Company.Name, Company.Reg FROM Company WHERE Name LIKE '%''" + Name + "''%'";
```

Here is the function:

```
public object CompanySearch(string Name)
        {
            using (PCE)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
                try
                {
                    List<CompanySearch> cm = new List<CompanySearch>();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                    command.Connection = con;
                    "SELECT Company.Name, Company.Reg FROM Company WHERE Name LIKE '%''" + Name + "''%'";
                    con.Open();
                    //process the sql execute etc
                }
            }
        }
```

Is the way I reading *Name* correctly?

I tested without `'   '` , however I get an exception message as follow:

```
"ExceptionMessage": "Incorrect syntax near 'Mysearch'.",
```

---

### UPDATE

```
SELECT Company.Name, Company.Reg
FROM Company
WHERE CompanyName LIKE '%MySearch%';
```

This is the code that I execute in SSMS, and it went sucess.
However it doesnt work on my C#

Comment: Your query is missing a `FROM`, and you got too many single quotes.. And, perhaps most importantly, you should parameterize your query.

Comment: Once you've got it working, try replacing `Mysearch` with `Mysearch' ; DROP TABLE Company; -- ` (in the UI). By the way, you should back up your database before attempting this. Once you've realised the damage SQL injection can do, see HoneyBadger's suggestion of parameterising your query.

Comment: Oh, and you don't assign your query, it's just an unrelated, solitary string which should give an error long before you come close to executing this,

Comment: You should read up on SQL Injection and why you shouldn't do what you're doing. Try and make sure you use parameters instead (in this case a param for 'Name')

Comment: Hi @HoneyBadger sry for typo, for actual I did write a `FROM` there, I already updated my question.

Comment: So may I say is this type of injection is not advisable? I should go for the answer that provided by Pitming Sir

Comment: Hi @John actually *MySearch* is what user input `Name=MySearch`, so is it that I am missing a ' at behind?

Comment: @Lawraoke Yes, but if the user inputs `MySearch' ; DROP TABLE Company; -- ` then the final query will be: `SELECT Company.Name, Company.Reg FROM Company WHERE CompanyName LIKE '%MySearch' ; DROP TABLE Company; -- %';`: Two SQL commands (a select and a drop table) and then a comment. This is why you should use parameters instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should always avoid to "manually build" your own query. This is the best way to have SQL Injection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Secondary, you should used Parameter in your query

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Company.Name, Company.Reg WHERE Name LIKE @companyName", connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@companyName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Name;
```

**But in 2020, you should use an ORM instead of building your own query.** This is far better to save time and avoid bugs.
Have a look at EF Core (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/ef/) or Dapper (https://stackexchange.github.io/Dapper/), ...

Comment: Hi @Pritming Sir, thanks for your answer, do you have more example on your parameters?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I try, it worked for me...

```
 public object CompanySearch(string Name)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            try
            {
                List<CompanySearch> cs = new List<CompanySearch>();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                command.Connection = con;
                command.CommandText = "SELECT Name, Reg, FROM Company WHERE Name LIKE '%" + Name + "%'";
                con.Open();
                //process the sql execute etc
            }
        }
    }
```

However, a good practice is to parameterize your query that mentioned by @HoneyBadger